# Div on top of another div - border overlap like a tab

Tags: html, tabs, overlap

Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xmcufcuq/

```
.ui-topbanner {
    color:#000;
    height: 31px;
    background-color: #f2e9da;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d9cebc;
}
.ui-topbanner-title {
    position:relative;
    top:4px;
    left:15px;
    height:26px;
    line-height:26px;
    padding:0 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#000;
    border:1px solid #d9cebc;
    background-color:#fff;
    z-index:98;
    font-size:.7rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.ui-topsubbanner {
    position:relative;
    color:#000;
    height: 33px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f7f1e8 0%, #f4ecdf 100%);
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #efe8da;
    z-index:1;
}


<div class="ui-topbanner"><div class="ui-topbanner-title">Music Tracks</div>    </div>
<div class="ui-topsubbanner">test</div>
```

And this is what I want to accomplish:

[image]

It should be displaying like a "tab". z-index and position:relative doesn't work.

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/xmcufcuq/1/) what you want?

Comment: or with relative postitioning see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/xmcufcuq/2/)

Comment: Awesome, so easy... Thanks! :)

Comment: Great...:) glad that it worked..could you please upvote my answer if it really helped you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/xmcufcuq/2/)

Change the css for `ui-topbanner-title` as follows

```
.ui-topbanner-title {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    left: 15px;
    height: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #d9cebc;
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 98;
    font-size: .7rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

And if you want to do it with absolute positioning, see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/xmcufcuq/1/)

and the CSS for `ui-topbanner-title` would be like

```
.ui-topbanner-title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    left: 15px;
    height: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #d9cebc;
    border-bottom: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 98;
    font-size: .7rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what i tried: Updated the height property to remove the bottom border:

```
.ui - topbanner{
    color:#000;
    height: 31px;
    background - color: #f2e9da;
    border - bottom: 1px solid #d9cebc;
}

.ui - topbanner - title{
    position:relative;
    top:4px;
    left:15px;
    height:28px;
    line - height:26px;
    padding:0 10px;
    display:inline - block;
    color:#000;
    background - color:#fff;
    font - size:.7rem;
    border - top - left - radius: 5px;
    border - top - right - radius: 5px;
    border:1px solid #d9cebc;

}

.ui - topsubbanner{
    position:relative;
    color:#000;
    height: 33px;
    background: -webkit - linear - gradient(top, #f7f1e8 0 % , #f4ecdf 100 % );
    border - top: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: Also removed the z-index properties.

Answer (score 0):

Add two additional properties to your .ui-topbanner-title class:

```
bottom: -5px;
border-bottom: none;
```

Additionaly remove:

```
top: 4px
```

With this change you can archieve your goal.

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c99qLmoj/)